# Previous article in Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I implemented a prev/next post method in my blog rails application but the previous method is giving errors. Not sure what to

```
# app/models/post.rb

def next
  Post.where("id > ?", id).limit(1).first
end

def prev
  Post.where("id < ?", id).limit(1).first
end
```

Then in my view:

```
# app/views/posts/show.html.erb

<%= link_to "Prev Post", @post.prev %>
<%= link_to "Next Post", @post.next %>
```

"Next" works perfectly, but "prev" seems to link to the very first post written instead of the one before it. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you didn't specify sort order. I wouldn't be suprised if `next` also didn't work (sometimes). When you rely on order of things, specify it explicitly.

```
def next
  Post.where("id > ?", id).order(id: :asc).limit(1).first
end

def prev
  Post.where("id < ?", id).order(id: :desc).limit(1).first
end
```

Comment: That did it, thank you very much! However now I have a slightly different problem. I created "draft" and "published" states for posts and I have `.where(published: true)` added to my index and show methods so non-authenticated users can't see posts in a draft state. Is there any way I can have the next and prev methods skip posts that are in a draft state? Right now if you're not authenticated it will just take you to the 404 page if you click next or prev towards an unpublished post.

Comment: Just add the corresponding clauses to the query. `.where.not(status: 'draft')` or something

Comment: `Post.where("id > ?", id).where(published: true).order(id: :asc).limit(1).first` worked perfectly. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.last`

```
def prev
  Post.where("id < ?", id).limit(1).last
end
```